# Word for the noise made by a propeller airplane passing overhead?

Tags: single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

What is the  onomatopoeic word for the noise made by a small twin prop airplane passing overhead?

For the story I'm writing, it's it's a small twin engine airplane flying nearby. So either a *buzz* nor a *roar* nor a *rumble* captures the sound.

Comment: A Cessna 152 or a squadron of B17s?

Comment: Don't answer in comments. If you have an answer, write an answer (that is, write a good answer, backing up what you suggest).

Comment: To me that sounds like the Mayo One helicopter going overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Drone" might be a good word, but it's not *really* onomanopoeic...

"Brrrr" might be a good onomatopoeia, but it's not really a word lol.

Comment: Drone sounds good. I think it is onomatopoeic. 

Her father drones on and on about politics. He's spoiled every family dinner.

Also - the plane in the story is actually one of the first drone aircraft. A TV guided Interstate TDR-1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_TDR)

We'll go with drroooooone. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that most references to airplanes are to jets, due to their ubiquity.  So I think what you really want to know is what sound a propeller makes.  I think **whir** works well.

Google agrees [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roar%20of%20the%20propeller%2C%20buzz%20of%20the%20propeller%2C%20whir%20of%20the%20propeller&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croar%20of%20the%20propeller%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuzz%20of%20the%20propeller%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhir%20of%20the%20propeller%3B%2Cc0).  This is particularly interesting if you switch between American and British English. Propellers only roar in Britain.  In America they never roar.  They whir and buzz.  :)

I guess it depends on your audience.

Answer (score 1):

**Rumble** from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rumble):

*to make a low heavy rolling sound*

> [e.g.](https://www.bard.edu/cep/blog/?p=13908) The **rumble** of an airplane overhead. The whistle of a passing train. Garbage trucks backing up. Construction machinery and jackhammering. All of these sounds fall into the background of your attention when you’re used to them, but how might this noise be affecting you over time?

Comment: That would be apt for a B17 but not for a Cessna 152.